# Cannot sign out with AuthenticationManager

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm trying to sign out a user whenever he/she presses a button. This is the method being called.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    using (var log = new Log("AccountController.LogOff()"))
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

When the user presses the button, the method DOES get hit, but the user is never signed out. No exceptions occurs, the user simply doesn't get signed out.

Comment: are you using an anchor when you say button?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What do you mean by an "anchor"?

Comment: <a href="">LogOff</a> tag

Comment: I'm using a form. `@Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post)` followed by the following tag; `<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">sign out</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
public ActionResult Logoff()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: No difference, I'm still not getting signed out.

Comment: @Detilium The reason AuthenticationManager.SignOut() fails is that Response.SetStatus(HttpStatusCode.SeeOther) internally ends the response:

public static void SetStatus(this HttpResponseBase response, int httpStatusCode)
{
  response.StatusCode = httpStatusCode;
  response.End();
}

Comment: What do you mean "working or not"? The initial answer did not work no, and I'm not sure I understand the comment. So the Http reponse ends, what's the solution to that? The method you posted in the comment? Could you format your comment better?

Comment: @Detilium please try small line of code after FormsAuthentication.SignOut();  i.e Session.Abondon().....

Comment: Still not working. I'm still logged in. 
Whenever I log out, the application should redirect to the index in the home controller. As the HomeController checks for the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, and I 'should' be logged out, the application should redirect me to the login page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111598/discussion-between-stylishcoder-and-detilium).

Answer (score 0):

LogOff function has [HttpPost] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] tags. So it's waiting a form which is sending an AntiForgeryToken. So you have to set your button for this situation.

Your Log Off button have to look like this in your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
                                {
                                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
                                }
```

Comment: Has your Html.BeginForm an id? Like that: @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post **, new { id = "logoutForm" }** ))

Comment: Yes. Otherwise I wouldn't hit the method in the controller like I do, as the `a` tag wouldn't know what form to hit, thereby what action to hit.

Comment: Did you try to logoff without "using" block? Is it working without that part?